# Why don't Web Fonts appear in developer tools Network tab?

Tags: web, browser

I was just wondering why fonts added via:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'myfont';    
    src: url('/webfonts/myfont-Regular.eot');
}
```

Don't show up in the *Network* tab in (Chrome or Firefox) developer tools?

(I tried to google this, but its difficult to phrase)